# Почему макротаска порожденная микротаской выполняется последней?

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, promise

почему setTimeout в блоке then  выполняется последним?

Насколько я знаю, следующая задача из очереди макрозадач выполняется после завершения предыдущей.

```js
console.log(1);

setTimeout(() => console.log(2), 0);

new Promise((res, rej) => {
  console.log(4);
  console.log(5)
  res(3)
}).then(res => setTimeout(() => console.log(res)));

setTimeout(() => console.log(6));
```

Comment: Она выполняется не последней, просто у вас в then стоит setTimeout, который положит выполнение кода в конец очереди, где как раз перед ней есть задачи на вывод 2 и 6

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае идет путаница между *выполнением `setTimeout`* и *выполнением `callback` переданного в `setTimeout`*.

Как только эту путаницу убрать все станет понятно:

1. сначала выполняется глобальная макрозадача
2. в ней выполняются синхронные вызовы, добавляются микрозадачи, добавляются новые макрозадачи
3. выполняются все микрозадачи
4. переходит выполнение к следующей макрозадаче

Если применить это к коду в вопросе:

```
// основная макрозадача
console.log(1);

// планирование новой макрозадачи 1
setTimeout(() => console.log(2), 0);

// планирование микрозадачи
new Promise((res, rej) => {// код в этом блоке выполняется синхронно, поэтому  вывод происходит сразу же
  console.log(4);
  console.log(5)
  res(3)
})
// callback переданный в then выполнится на шаге микрозадач
.then(res => 
    // данный код планирует новую макрозадачу 2
    setTimeout(() => console.log(res)));

// планирование новой макрозадачи 3
setTimeout(() => console.log(6));
```

Как видно, в коде есть планирование трех макро задач, при этом 1 и 3 планируются в основной задаче и макрозадача 3 планируется на этапе выполнения микрозадач, поэтому она и выполнится позже в данном случае

И небольшая [визуализация](https://www.jsv9000.app/?code=Y29uc29sZS5sb2coMSk7DQoNCnNldFRpbWVvdXQoZnVuY3Rpb24gdGFzazEoKXsgY29uc29sZS5sb2coMil9LCAwKTsNCg0KbmV3IFByb21pc2UoZnVuY3Rpb24gcHJvbWlzZShyZXMsIHJlaikgew0KICBjb25zb2xlLmxvZyg0KTsNCiAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coNSkNCiAgcmVzKDMpDQp9KQ0KLnRoZW4oDQogIGZ1bmN0aW9uIHRoZW4ocmVzKXsgDQogICAgc2V0VGltZW91dChmdW5jdGlvbiB0YXNrMigpew0KICAgICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2cocmVzKQ0KICAgIH0pDQogIH0pOw0KDQpzZXRUaW1lb3V0KGZ1bmN0aW9uIHRhc2szKCkge2NvbnNvbGUubG9nKDYpfSk7)